# Can't decompress firmware

Tags: firmware, decompress, firmware-analysis

I'm trying to reverse engineer a firmware for a vape mod. I've downloaded it from their official website. First I tried dissassemble it in IDA but it couldn't identify any architecture in it. Then I tried to examine it with binvis.io and it looked like this [image]

So judging from this image I made a conclusion that this file is compressed. After that I opened it in HxD. And I've got there some repeating bytes but I couldn't figure out what they mean yet.[image]

I would be very pleased if you could give me the direction for my next steps.
And if you want to study that file for yourself, you can download it here. [Firmware for asmodus minikin boost](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0008/7484/0129/files/MiniKinV1.5BoostMod.firmware?8078543727848484856)

And also you can check out their official firmware updater tool if this helps. [Upgrade tool](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0008/7484/0129/files/UpgradeV1.1.zip?15970523724909510905)

Answer (score 1):

The binary is likely scrambled. At least the one for mine (Eleaf) is. Maybe there is a chance to read the unscrambled image out of the hardware using JTAG (if not disabled)
The Eleaf Controller is labled "M091" and is a 48 PIN but did not find any routed JTAG connection onboard.
A first step to find out what chip it is could be a check to which pins the crystal is connected to.